Vertical alignment on cells for tabularray package
I know this question comes a lot and I've done my fair share of research and found no solution for my problem.
I'm trying to align the cell contents on the middle of the cell as well as the center, and I've already tried using the Q[c] and Q[m] specifications for columns and rows respectively, but without much success.
My code is as follows:
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Intervalos de t associados a cada estrutura perovskita.}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec     = {Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},
        rowspec     = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
        row{odd}    = {bg = gray!50},
        row{even}   = {bg = gray!25},
        row{1}      = {bg = gray!75, font = \bfseries},
        column{3}   = {wd = 2.5cm}
    }
        t & Estrutura & Causa & \SetCell[c=2]{c,m} Exemplo & & Cartão ICSD\\
        > 1.00 & Hexagonal & $r_A>r_X$ ou $r_B<(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{LaMnO3} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Images/LaMnO3_37317.png} & \# 37317\\
        (0.80 , 1.00) & Cúbica & $r_A\approx r_X$ e $r_B\approx(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{SrTiO3} & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Images/SrTiO3_19796.png} & \# 19796 \\
        (0.71 , 0.80) & Ortorrômbica & $r_A<r_X$ ou $r_B>(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{CaTiO3} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Images/CaTiO3_19792.png} & \# 19792
    \end{tblr}
    \caption*{Fonte: Adaptado de \citecall{li_stabilizing_2016} e \citecall{li_formability_O_2004}}
    \label{tab:Goldschimidt}
\end{table}

The result obtained is the one showed in the picture bellow:

I've also come across this package while researching about the topic in this forum, arriving at the following post How to vertically-center the text of the cells?
P.S. Please ignore the cite commands, since this is part of a formal university work they must be present but should not affect the overall code performance.

Use valign=... from the adjustbox package to change the alignment of the images

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You need to move image baseline to its vertical center. For example you can use the adjustbox package with option in \includegraphique  \includegraphics[valign=c]{image} 
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Intervalos de t associados a cada estrutura perovskita.}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec     = {Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},
        rowspec     = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
        row{odd}    = {bg = gray!50},
        row{even}   = {bg = gray!25},
        row{1}      = {bg = gray!75, font = \bfseries},
        column{3}   = {wd = 2.5cm}
    }
                t & Estrutura & Causa & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Exemplo & & Cartão ICSD\\
        > 1.00 & Hexagonal & $r_A>r_X$ ou $r_B<(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{LaMnO3} & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image-a} & \# 37317\\
        (0.80 , 1.00) & Cúbica & $r_A\approx r_X$ e $r_B\approx(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{SrTiO3} & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{example-image-b} & \# 19796 \\
        (0.71 , 0.80) & Ortorrômbica & $r_A<r_X$ ou $r_B>(\sqrt{2}-1)r_X$ & \ch{CaTiO3} & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image-c} & \# 19792
    \end{tblr}
    \caption*{Fonte: Adaptado de %\citecall{li_stabilizing_2016} e \citecall{li_formability_O_2004}  %unknow  command
        }
    \label{tab:Goldschimidt}
\end{table}

\end{document}


